# How do I configure libvirt-guests on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

In RH-based distros, this seems to be in /etc/sysconfig. It appears it has moved in Ubuntu, but to where?

Comment: 22?  So this is for Ubuntu Core 22 systems?

Comment: Only Ubuntu Core has version number in the YY format such as 22. Ubuntu desktop and servers have version number in YY.MM format, such as 22.04 and 22.10. Please edit your question and specify the correct Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/libvirt-guests
is the config file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.